# How to quickly return the number of rows in a distributed hypertable with more than 100 million rows in TimescaleDB?

Tags: timescaledb

In a 'vanilla' **PostgreSQL 12.7** database, I generally run the following query to learn the **estimated number of rows** in tables with 100+ million rows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
-- Return the estimated number of rows for the given table
----------------------------------------------------------
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate_number_of_rows
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = to_regclass('name_of_some_big_table');
```

This type of query doesn't work for a **distributed hypertable** on our **multi-node** **TimescaleDB** installation.

I checked the [TimescaleDB API Reference](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/#apis-grouped-by-related-feature) but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Is there such a straightforward query to quickly return the estimated number of rows in a distributed hypertable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TimescaleDB provides `approximate_row_count` function, which is described in the documentation [here](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/analytics/approximate_row_count/). The accuracy depends when ANALYZE or VACUUM was run last time.

For your table the query will be:

```sql
SELECT approximate_row_count('name_of_some_big_table');
```